# What are some physics books written in dialogue or story form, e.g., a teacher explaining to a student?

Tags: resource-recommendations, education

A good example would be [How to Teach Quantum Physics to Your Dog](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1416572295) by [Chad Orzel](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/166/chad-orzel).

Comment: Have you tried George Gamow's Mr Tompkins in Paperback?

Comment: @Declan I just checked out the [preview](http://www.amazon.com/Mr-Tompkins-Paperback-George-Gamow/dp/0521447712) on Amazon...definitely fits the criteria! And it seems like a very great book!

Comment: This question (v1) sounds like a list question.

Answer (score 2):

[*How to teach Relativity to your Dog*](http://dogphysics.com/relativity_info.html), also by [Chad Orzel](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/166/chad-orzel) - it's just as good as *How to teach Quantum Physics to your dog!* It's written in a similarly hilariously conversational style between Orzel and his dog. It's readable and accessible, but of course not especially highbrow - it's a fun introduction.

Comment: No offence, but please do add why this book counts to OP's query; merely adding a book's name is what is discouraged here. Please add some details as to how it serves OP, its pros or/and cons etcetera. Otherwise, your answer would be deleted.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know about the policy behind answering these questions